# I have spending predictors and most spend nothing

Tags: regression, assumptions

I am running a linear regression with income at closure from a program the dependent variable. Some of the key predictor variables are how much we spend on a customer. In very many cases (maybe 90 percent of the cases) we spend nothing. So 90 percent of the customers have the same level for these predictors.

I was trying to figure out how this would influence the results or if it violates a regression assumption. I can't think of anything I have run across on this for interval variables (some believe it attenuates slopes for categorical variables, but my variables are interval). Any comments.

Comment: Might this work: make two different models where the first is a logistic model on [spend or not spend]. If spend or not spend can be accurately modeled, then make a second regression model of the spend-only data. If both of these models are accurate, then data can be fed into the first model, and when a spend is predicted then the data can be fed into the second model to predict the amount of spend.

Comment: Would it matter if the predictors of spend not spend were different than the ones that predicted income at closure (the model I initially ran)? They likely would be. is it valid in regression, I have not encountered this in an analysis, to modify the original linear regression to those who spend only? Then the results would be, of those that we spend this type of money on the impact is this. I could use all the variables in the first model, including other types of spend, just limit it to those who spend.

Comment: If you can accurately determine "not spend" with one model, that can be used to determine if spend is zero. Make a separate model for spend of more than zero. This should work better than a single model.

Comment: This doesn't violate any assumptions of linear regression. However, I would add a dummy variable that takes value 1 whenever all of those spending predictors are zero and 0 otherwise. In other words, create a new column in your dataset indicating whether a certain case falls within those 90 percent of customers you describe. This will allow for a special adjustment to be assigned to that situation. If you want the coefficients for other parameters to be different between the zero spending and the nonzero spending cases as well, you can add interaction terms with this new dummy variable.